# Abnormal distance in acronym list

Tags: acronyms, makeindex

I have made a list of acronyms and at first everything looked fine. Once I added tRNA as acronym the distance between tRNA and TSH seem to be smaller than from the other acronyms.

Has anyone an idea why and how can I solve this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}


\makenoidxglossaries
\newacronym{pcr}{PCR}{Polymerase Chain Reaction}
\newacronym{trna}{tRNA}{transfer ribonucleic acid}
\newacronym{mttrna}{mt-tRNA}{mitochondrial  transfer ribonucleic acid}
\newacronym{melas}{MELAS}{mitochondrial encephalopathy lactic acidosis}
\newacronym{tsh}{TSH}{thyroid stimulating hormone}
\newacronym{acth}{ACTH}{adrenocorticotropic hormone}
\newacronym{elisa}{ELISA}{Enzyme-linked Immunosorbent Assay}
\newacronym{hek293ft}{HEK293FT}{human embryonic kidney 293 FT cells}
\newacronym{u87}{U87}{Uppsala 87 Malignant Glioma cells}
\printnoidxglossaries


\begin{document}
    
    \printnoidxglossaries
    
    TEXT:
    \gls{acth}
    \gls{elisa}
    \gls{hek293ft}
    \gls{pcr}
    \gls{u87}
    \gls{trna}
    \gls{tsh}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually a feature, not a bug, as the acronym list is printed as an index. Thus tNRA and TSH get closer because they both begin with `t`.

You can add the option `nogroupskip`, described on page 160 of the documentation of package `glossaries`, to disable the vertical gap, and get:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist,nopostdot,nomain,nogroupskip]{glossaries}
% I've also added a `nomain' to remove the warnings

\makenoidxglossaries
\newacronym{pcr}{PCR}{Polymerase Chain Reaction}
\newacronym{trna}{tRNA}{transfer ribonucleic acid}
\newacronym{mttrna}{mt-tRNA}{mitochondrial  transfer ribonucleic acid}
\newacronym{melas}{MELAS}{mitochondrial encephalopathy lactic acidosis}
\newacronym{tsh}{TSH}{thyroid stimulating hormone}
\newacronym{acth}{ACTH}{adrenocorticotropic hormone}
\newacronym{elisa}{ELISA}{Enzyme-linked Immunosorbent Assay}
\newacronym{hek293ft}{HEK293FT}{human embryonic kidney 293 FT cells}
\newacronym{u87}{U87}{Uppsala 87 Malignant Glioma cells}


\begin{document}
    
    \printnoidxglossaries
    
    TEXT:
    \gls{acth}
    \gls{elisa}
    \gls{hek293ft}
    \gls{pcr}
    \gls{u87}
    \gls{trna}
    \gls{tsh}
\end{document}
```